Why I cannot see the table and the sequence id from the mapped entity in spring boot/posgresql?
As a new spring developer, I am trying to map the entity with the database
However, I am unable to see the "customer table" and the "sequence" ids
Customer class
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer{
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(
        name = "customer_id_sequence",
        sequenceName = "customer_id_sequence"
)
@GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
        generator = "customer_id_sequence"
)
private  Integer id;
private String name;
private String email;
private Integer age;
public Customer(){

}

Customer Service
@Service
public class CustomerService {

private final CustomerDao customerDao;

public CustomerService(CustomerDao customerDao) {
    
    this.customerDao = customerDao;
}

public List<Customer> getAllCustomers(){

    return customerDao.selectAllCustomers();
}

public Customer getCustomer(Integer id){

    return customerDao.selectCustomersById(id)
            .orElseThrow(()->new ResourceNotFound(("customer with id [%s] not found".formatted(id))));
}

}
Customer Controller
@RestController
public class CustomerController {
private final CustomerService customerService;

public CustomerController(CustomerService customerService) {

    this.customerService = customerService;
}

@GetMapping("/api/v1/customers")
public List< Customer> getCustomers(){
    return customerService.getAllCustomers();
}

@GetMapping("/api/v1/customers/{customerId}")
public Customer getCustomer(@PathVariable("customerId")Integer customerId){

    return customerService.getCustomer(customerId);
}

}
@Repository

public class CustomerDataAccessService implements CustomerDao{

//Database
private final static List customers;
Postgres
postgres database
Issue:
enter image description here
Regarding properties

jpa:
   hibernate:
     ddl-auto: create-drop

   properties:
    hibernate:
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
      format_sql: true
    show_sql: false


Logs
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v3.1.10)

2024-04-29T09:11:50.485-04:00  INFO 17056 --- [           main] 
com.kyleshyro.Main                       : Starting Main using 
Java 17.0.10 with PID 17056 (C:\Users\antho\OneDrive\Desktop\Spring Project Full Stack\drivecraft\drivecraft\target\classes started by antho in C:\Users\antho\OneDrive\Desktop\Spring Project Full Stack\drivecraft\drivecraft)
2024-04-29T09:11:50.487-04:00  INFO 17056 --- [           main] com.kyleshyro.Main                       : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-04-29T09:11:50.851-04:00  INFO 17056 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-04-29T09:11:50.869-04:00  INFO 17056 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 10 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-04-29T09:11:51.169-04:00  INFO 17056 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2024-04-29T09:11:51.175-04:00  INFO 17056 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-04-29T09:11:51.175-04:00  INFO 17056 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.19]
2024-04-29T09:11:51.245-04:00  INFO 17056 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-04-29T09:11:51.246-04:00  INFO 17056 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 730 ms
2024-04-29T09:11:51.321-04:00  INFO 17056 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-04-29T09:11:51.439-04:00  INFO 17056 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@59fc6d05
2024-04-29T09:11:51.440-04:00  INFO 17056 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-04-29T09:11:51.467-04:00  INFO 17056 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-04-29T09:11:51.500-04:00  INFO 17056 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.22.Final
2024-04-29T09:11:51.502-04:00  INFO 17056 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
2024-04-29T09:11:51.681-04:00  INFO 17056 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-04-29T09:11:52.339-04:00  INFO 17056 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2024-04-29T09:11:52.341-04:00  INFO 17056 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-04-29T09:11:52.385-04:00  WARN 17056 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2024-04-29T09:11:52.614-04:00  INFO 17056 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2024-04-29T09:11:52.620-04:00  INFO 17056 --- [           main] com.kyleshyro.Main                       : Started Main in 2.401 seconds (process running for 2.816)

